# Can i crop a part of a website and put in my WPF web browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I try to create a WPF web browser inside my grid. The size of my grid isn't big enough to fit in a whole html. Let say i want to put in the google search in my web browser. Can i just crop the middle part of google.com (as shown in the image below) and put in my web browser? Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: that would hide the copyright notice, so it's illegal

Answer (score 0):

That's one option, but it's a bit of a hack.

An alternative solution is to modify the DOM of the webpage you load and apply a CSS zoom of about 80% (or whatever is appropriate) so the entire page can be displayed.

You could also apply CSS box clipping to the root `<html>` or `<body>` element to achieve a less messy result.

Comment: hmm....sounds tricky. Actually i am new to this, can you provide any link or example for me? Tqvm C=